# access to a variable inside the function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, croppie

For example I have this JavaScript function:

```
function createCroppie() {
  var crop = new Croppie(document.getElementById('js-image-editor'), {
      enableExif: true,
      showZoomer: true,
      viewport: { width: y, height: y, type: 'square'},
      boundary: { width: x, height: x}
  });
}
```

now I need to access to the "crop" variable for using in these codes:

```
  $('.fa-save').on('click', function (ev) {
       crop.result ({
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
      }).then(function () {
        console.log('upload image complete');
      });
    });
```

Since the second block of code that I wrote here is not in the same function, how can I access to the "crop" variable in createCroppie function?

Comment: `return crop` in `createCroppie` then `createCroppie().crop` is what you want ... though the code you wrote, you may as well not have that function at all

Comment: Declare crop `( var crop= null;)` as global variable. Just replace `var crop` to `crop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function variables are scoped within the function, unless closure is used. As Senal pointed out the first solution is to use a global scope for the variable.

To rewrite using closure:

```
function createCroppie() {
  var crop = new Croppie(document.getElementById('js-image-editor'), {
      enableExif: true,
      showZoomer: true,
      viewport: { width: y, height: y, type: 'square'},
      boundary: { width: x, height: x}
  }
  return crop;
// or return this;
// this being the elements of the function as an object.
  );
}

crop = createCroppie();
```

Looking up Croppie documentation it is based on creating a closure to return a object with its variables. No need to wrap a function around it.

```
var myCroppie = new Croppie(document.getElementById('js-image-editor'), {
          enableExif: true,
          showZoomer: true,
          viewport: { width: y, height: y, type: 'square'},
          boundary: { width: x, height: x}
      };
```

However, you could use closure to extend the library.

```
function createCroppie() {
  var crop = new Croppie(document.getElementById('js-image-editor'), {
      enableExif: true,
      showZoomer: true,
      viewport: { width: y, height: y, type: 'square'},
      boundary: { width: x, height: x}
  }
  function say(message) {
       console.log(message);
       return this;
  }
  return this;
  );
}

crop = createCroppie();
```

Now crop is a new croppie with a log function, and this, (this being the following not the elements of the object of the function), works.

```
  $('.fa-save').on('click', function (ev) {
       crop.log('clicked').result ({
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
      }).then(function () {
        console.log('upload image complete');
      });
    });
```

Note, the say function of the closure function needs to return "this", (Javascript this), so as to include the .result function allowing crop.log.result() to exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, i appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you initialize Croppie before the click event, you can do the following

```
var myCroppie;

function createCroppie() {
   myCroppie = new Croppie(document.getElementById('js-image-editor'), {
      enableExif: true,
      showZoomer: true,
      viewport: { width: y, height: y, type: 'square'},
      boundary: { width: x, height: x}
   });
}

 createCroppie();

 $('.fa-save').on('click', function (ev) {
     myCroppie.result ({
       type: 'canvas',
       size: 'viewport'
     }).then(function () {
        console.log('upload image complete');
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i appreciate it